# Vue 3 component tests with pinia is giving error "getActivePinia() was called but there was no active Pinia"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia, vitest

I'm trying to test a component that uses a Pinia store, even following the documentation correctly, I'm getting this error:

```
"getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
```

I've also tried to call **setActivePinia(createPinia())** in beforeEach, but without success.

This is my code

```
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MainFilter, {
      global: {
        plugins: [
          createTestingPinia({
            createSpy: vi.fn
          })
        ]
      }
    });

    expect(wrapper.find('div')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Component:

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { clientsStore } from '@/stores/clients';

const store = clientsStore();

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        id: ''
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      store.updateMyStore(this.form);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please, provide a component. I'd expected it to work.

Comment: @EstusFlask I added the code to the component that I use the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Pinia store is accessed too early, this incidentally isn't a problem in the application due to an order in which the modules are imported.

Pinia uses store composables instead of store instances to avoid the early instantiation and provide an option to provide custom Pinia instance. Store composable is supposed to be called directly in place where it's used. In case of options API it can be exposed on the instance in lifecycle hook, e.g. `data`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      store: useClientsStore()
      form: {
        id: ''
      }
    };
  }
```